# Windows 10 Technical Preview Install is Freezing

Tags: freeze, windows-installation, windows-10-preview

I'm trying to install the Windows 10 Technical Preview on my Acer 751h laptop. I've downloaded the iso and used rufus to create a bootable USB. When I choose "Install," and then "Custom," the install process starts, but freezes at 0% on "copying files." While it's frozen, I'm unable to move the mouse, and the hard drive activity light is on. Any help?

Comment: Check if your iso is not corrupted. Are you using Rufus correctly? How big is your USB stick? Does the HDD light flash or just stay on? Have you tried leaving it on for some time? eg 30min

Comment: The HDD light stays on. I did leave it on for an hour while I left the house, when I got back it was still frozen at 0%. I'm using Rufus at default settings. The USB stick is 8 GB. I've redownloaded the iso and will update here after I try again.

Comment: Update: I checked the SHA-1 for the iso. It's verified, so it's not the iso, it would seem. I went out and bought a new USB stick, and tried that. Still freezing.

Comment: Your 751h has an Atom Z520 CPU which does not support 64bit. Was your iso 32bit or 64bit? Also what's your RAM and HDD space?

Comment: And check if your CPU supports PAE and  NX. http://www.technize.net/how-to-check-if-your-processor-supports-pae-nx-and-sse2-for-windows-8-installation/ (oh wait, you have VT-x so it should be supported. Go into BIOS and see if they are enabled.)

Comment: @RsyaStudios 2GB ram and 120 GB Samsung 840 evo SSD. The ISO, of course was 32 bit. Unfortunately, my BIOS doesn't seem to have an option to enable VT-x even though the CPU has it as a feature.

Comment: [Try Microsoft's usb tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool), works every time for me.

Comment: Tried that. I still encountered the freezing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I burned the install iso to the hard drive I wanted to install it on and booted from there. Windows 10 installed correctly.

Thanks to everyone who gave feedback, I guess it just doesn't like booting from usb...

Answer (score 0):

Is the USB port that you are using a USB 3.0 port? Using USB installation media tools like Rufus and the Windows DVD/USB Tool can break compatibility with USB 3.0. In order to create USB media that supports the USB 3.0 drivers, you should use DiskPart to make the USB stick partition active and then simply copy all of the files from the Windows 10 Technical Preview ISO into that partition.

Comment: Well, the laptop is 5 years old and I'm almost certain that it's not a USB 3.0 port for that reason.

Answer (score -2):

Can confirm same behavior on Asus 1101HA. Windows 10, Windows 7 hangs after several seconds at 0% copy. Used RUFUS. Did install on another laptop as workaround.

Comment: This does not really answer the proposed question, there is no doubt the author is having trouble, so a confirmation it happens to somebody else is not really an answer to how to prevent it from happening.